# using double powersupplies

Tags: power-supply, parallel, redundancy

I have 2 computers (home PC's). Both are connected to the internet through a router/switch.

The router is always powered, regardless when one (or both PC's) are going standby.

Idea is, to power the router from the PC power supply (by homemade cable ofc.), so When PC goes standby the 12 Volt are shut off and so the router (note also that this avoids the router power adapter).

The trick is to have this happen from both two PC's - aka power on/off the router by a common connection from both. If both (or only one powered) are off/on the router follows, and we save the world energy.

I already have made such a connection - and it work fine. But I'm still concerned by any power/voltage imbalance between the two PC's.

Below is how I made the wiring with 2 protection diodes.

But still i think that one PSW could feed into the other. I also considered a relay which could isolate 100%, but this would give a short delay in power when shifting.

Are there any other wiring (or device/chip) to solve this perfectly.

Tx for any answers

[image]

Comment: It's a little non-orthodox to be doing this, but I see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you "think that one PSW could feed into the other"? ORing diodes is pretty much a standard solution to prevent this, recommended by PSU makers, e.g. http://www.kepcopower.com/support/diodes.htm. As long as the diodes are properly selected so they don't overheat, I don't see an issue here. You could use Schottky diodes to reduce the voltage drop seen by the router and simultaneously decrease power dissipation on themselves, but since you said it already works with the diodes you've tried... it seem a bit pointless to bother now.

The mismatched voltages are a problem when you want to *load-balance* the sources on a load (e.g. see http://www.codemsys.com/smps/Parallel.htm), but that issue seems irrelevant to your application as either PC source can presumably power its PC and the router (presumably a home model) comfortably.

There are slightly more expensive stock IC solutions for redundant power supplies, which is basically what you're doing from the router's perspective, (e.g. see http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva094/slva094.pdf), which have some additional advantages like almost zero voltage drop to the load, but they seem overkill for your application.

Comment: wow - I guess the 2 (first) answers buries my doubts. Nevertheless - I really enjoy when the PC standby power down the external equipment. This could allso include desktop speakers, label printer etc.etc. Note: The PC (ATX) power mfg. should incoorporate a DC connector on the back for such externals. Think how many mains adapters one could avoid.

Comment: Note that they don't need to. With the combination of a extension card bracket and some cable, you can power a router via its barrel connector using a cable to the connection on that bracket and then from it to the MOLEX connector on the power supply. Its up to you if the connection on the back of the computer is a MOLEX connector or something else.

Comment: Ya - I made a short extension with a male molex and a female DC connector on the outside. From here is required a male-male extension (I did'nt like to use  a male outside due to the non-isolated minus shaft). This is more cumbersome, but more safe. Next after this prototyping is making a real backplate with the connector (or 2-3 in row).